# Opencv canny edge detection crashes on Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

I'm new using OpenCV and when I try to apply the Canny detector, my App crashes. I've seen another post about the same but I tried it and nothing...

I use Android Studio 3.0, OpenCV 3.2.0 and my phone is Android 6.0.1.

This is my code. I tried lots of combinations and always fails when I try to apply the Canny detector. Please pay attention at the last method onCameraFrame...It works perfect with both Rgba and Gray image, but not with the Canny:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{


    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRgba, imgGray, imgCanny, wide;
    BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status){
            switch(status){
                case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:{
                    javaCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if(javaCameraView!=null)
            javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(javaCameraView!=null)
            javaCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.i(TAG, "Opencv loaded succesfully");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Opencv not loaded");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_2_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat (height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        imgGray = new Mat (height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        imgCanny = new Mat (height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        imgGray = inputFrame.gray();
        //mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        //Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.Canny(imgGray, imgCanny, 50, 150); //detector canny

        return imgCanny;
    }

}
```

I also like to know if it's possible to catch the image and save it into the gallery. Maybe with the onTouch method? Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there any error mesage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the app is crashing when it hits the Canny detector because of the wrong type of OpenCV Manager installed on your device, be it version number or central processor instruction set. Checking the correct version should be straightforward. Just go to the OpenCV-android-sdk\apk directory and check for the 3 (x.y.z) numbers after OpenCV_

The device should be crashing when it executes the Imgproc.Canny function call.

**Checking instruction set of Android devices for Windows**

To check the instruction set of your device, navigate to the adb (android debug bridge) directory commonly located at:

C:\Users\<'your username'>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
Run the command:

```
./adb.exe shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

After getting the correct instruction set, navigate back to the OpenCV-android-sdk\apk and locate the correct apk version and instruction set to be installed on your android device.

You can then transfer the apk to your device and install it. Another way I find useful is to navigate to the adb.exe directory and run the command:

```
./adb.exe install <path to OpenCV-android-sdk>/apk/OpenCV_x.y.z_Manager_x.yz_<platform instruction set>.apk
```

Apart from the steps above, make sure that you do not have any other environment variables that use other types of OpenCV Manager such as stating a different one in the Application.mk or build.gradle files.

After the steps above, your Canny detector should be able to run on your device without crashing.

As for the second part of your question on saving the image to the gallery, please refer to the capturing pictures part of the Camera/Camera2 API for android developers:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#capture-picture

Happy Developing :).

Answer (score 0):

Only OpenCV v3.1 worked for me for Canny Edge detection. Had problems with the higher versions (v3.4). Hope this helps!